# I was trying to make an excel sheet but it seems that it's not working

Tags: python-3.6, openpyxl

```py
import openpyxl
import pathlib

a = pathlib.Path("G:/myCourse_mhanned/19. SUPERHERO LEVEL Automate Excel Tasks with Python 3/1.1 Employees.xlsx.xlsx")
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(a)
print(workbook.sheetnames)
print(workbook.active)
sheet = workbook["EmployeeData"]
workbook.create_sheet("test_file")
workbook.save(a)
```

I expected to ad a new sheet but otherwise it gave me this permission error:
['EmployeeData', 'Salaries', 'Skills']

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/BMRL/PycharmProjects/pytrial/anuhabd.py", line 10, in 
    workbook.save(a)
  File "C:\Users\BMRL\PycharmProjects\pytrial\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\workbook.py", line 397, in save
    save_workbook(self, filename)
  File "C:\Users\BMRL\PycharmProjects\pytrial\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 292, in save_workbook
    archive = ZipFile(filename, 'w', ZIP_DEFLATED, allowZip64=True)
  File "C:\Users\BMRL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\zipfile.py", line 1204, in **init**
    self.fp = io.open(file, filemode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'G:\myCourse_mhanned\19. SUPERHERO LEVEL Automate Excel Tasks with Python 3\1.1 Employees.xlsx.xlsx'

Answer (score 0):

Use backslash instead of forward one that's due to windows paths that uses backslash `\`